# Creating something similar to this without using css grid and without using css flex

Tags: javascript, css

I need to create something like this

[image]

without using CSS grid or without using CSS flex for personal reasons I have a lot of issues with those methods in certain situations and yes they do generate

something like that but in certain situations they had failed me. If you guys can provide your own code method on how you would do this without using CSS grid or without using CSS flex please give me an example with your code. I wonder if I can do this with CSS only or do I

have to use JavaScript for this? If so then I don't mind either. Ignore that black thing i'm trying to recreate that gray container with how those images readjust it self inside that gray container and one last thing without using media queries I know this is possible without using them too. This is where i'm stuck at

```js
/*Do I have to use JavaScript for this? Yes or No??*/
```

```css
/*What else do I have to add??*/

#container{
  background-color: gray;
  width: 40%;
}

img{
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <img src='https://www.tomswallpapers.com/large/201610/75735.jpg'>
  <img src='https://www.tomswallpapers.com/large/201610/75735.jpg'>
  <img src='https://www.tomswallpapers.com/large/201610/75735.jpg'>
  <img src='https://www.tomswallpapers.com/large/201610/75735.jpg'>
  <img src='https://www.tomswallpapers.com/large/201610/75735.jpg'>
</div><!--</container>-->
```

Comment: If it's the window you resize, then perhaps [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)?

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/8fohse7x/

Comment: I have this feeling that no matter what you try, you will run into issues. Better to learn how to use CSS properly - `flexbox` and `grid` and all - and see how to solve their limitations than to build your own fake system that might have different limitations that are harder to see, harder to debug and where people can offer you less help. `flexbox` is well understood and you can post about it on Stack Overflow and ensure you get help. That is not the case for your custom solution.

Comment: OMG Chris G that's what I was looking for =) it gave that effect I was looking for just like that gif image can you provide a plain JavaScript version?

Comment: I want to reward you @ChrisG for the best answer if you can provide a plain JavaScript version on here I will like to give you points and reward you for the best answer if that is possible :)

Comment: @fsofb Done :) But you shouldn't limit yourself to hacky workarounds just because something failed in the past.

Comment: Well as soon as I get this working on IE I will tell you why I suggest this method instead of the css flex and grid method but hey @ChrisG I really appreciate that you are helping me out on this but sadly this is not working on Internet Explorer this is what I mean https://docs.google.com/document/d/19hJOyFLmhR_BCxzM40GXPwwO68Nq2msi9VmsbxJRlMc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way, using a resize event listener and some math:

```js
function resize() {
  var w = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.body).width) * 0.6;
  var times = Math.round(w / 150);
  var iw = w / times;
  
  Array.prototype.forEach.call( 
document.querySelectorAll('#container img'),
function(img){
  img.style.width = iw + "px";
  document.querySelector('#container').style.width = (iw * times + 1) + "px";
}
);

}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", resize);
window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <img src='https://www.tomswallpapers.com/large/201610/75735.jpg'>
  <img src='https://www.tomswallpapers.com/large/201610/75735.jpg'>
  <img src='https://www.tomswallpapers.com/large/201610/75735.jpg'>
  <img src='https://www.tomswallpapers.com/large/201610/75735.jpg'>
  <img src='https://www.tomswallpapers.com/large/201610/75735.jpg'>
</div>
<!--</container>-->
```

Comment: Hey Chris G I provided an edit of your code to have it work in IE. It now works on IE if you can kindly approve my edit on your code so future readers can use this method if they found this method to be useful as soon as you do that I will reward you of having the best answer. One last thing Chris G thank you so much for your help I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @fsofb I only got to this now but saw your edit and approved it :)

Comment: Thanks Chris G for every thing. I'm using your method to do amazing things now but I have a new post relating to your method because I added more things to your method if your interested in more points then follow this link if you want to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52913703/code-execute-perfectly-in-window-resize-but-with-window-restore-button-it-causes